# How was the appropriate death penalty decided for each sin?

Tags: halacha-theory, capital-punishment

There are four capital punishments (Skilah, Sreifah, Hereg and Chenek) and there seems to be a [hierarchy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82929/why-does-the-gemara-go-through-each-death-penalty) in terms of severity (heavy to light) but is there any discussion of how the specific crime merited a particular death or why a specific death method is appropriate for a crime? Is the death sentence a natural consequence (which would make it inherently tied in its method to the crime) or a punishment (so the severity matters but the particular method doesn't)?

If the goal is punishment then the penalty is simply death - how can we justify any method of killing that is more or less severe? Shouldn't the end result, death, be the point so we should use a method like we would in shechita, to get to the desired end as quickly (and painlessly) as possible?

Comment: There are 2 angles that I'm not following regarding this question: 1) Many of the types of death are enumerated in the Torah. E.g. gathering twigs on Shabbat is death by stoning. 2) Why do you assume that these types of death have a hierarchy?

Comment: @DanF is there a logic to associating a sin with a particular penalty? The linked question posits " Stoning is more severe than any other form of death penalty"

Comment: Sorry ... I hadn't seen the linked question which explains that there is some type of "hierarchy". For those specified in the Torah, I wouldn't assume a logical hierarchy to them. Perhaps, there is for the non-enumerated ones.

Comment: From your headline, it's not clear if your asking how, hermeneutically, Chazal derived a specific execution-type from the verses, or if you're asking for *taama dikra* - the reason behind the biblical commandment... I assume it's the latter(?)

Comment: IMSMC, if e.g. a convicted murderer is successfully avoiding his designated execution, he may be executed by other means, as necessary.  I don't recall if this is true of other capital crimes.

Comment: re the "painlessly" point - we do indeed derive from "*Love thy fellow as thyself*" - *bror lo mitha yafa* - choose the most humane execution.  However, that is *within* the specific mode prescribed by the Torah.  Thus, rather than burning at the stake one liable to burning, the convict is instead forced to swallow molten lead resulting in a quicker, somewhat more humane (and less disfiguring) death.

Comment: @Loewian I'm actually asking both the rabbinic method and the Torah-level reasoning (is there a consistent logic?) And I'm still wondering why, if the goal is "love they fellow" we don't adopt a painless method rather than a "more humane" one.

Comment: @rosends Those seem like two very different questions.  Also, clearly the concept of being most humane (at least physically) to a criminal is not an absolute, or G-d would not prescribe the death penalty to begin with.  Judaism in general focuses on balancing conflicting ideals, such as justice and mercy.  This case is no different.  Why specific crimes merit specific deaths, however, is a great set of questions - albeit also rather broad considering how many capital crimes there are.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that the written law is associated by commentators as more specifically describing a hypothetical, ideal law focused on theoretical justice (דין), whereas the oral law is focused more on integrating compassion (רחמים).  Thus, according to the Sages, a court that executes more than once in seventy years is considered murderous.  And Rabbi Akiva said had he been on a sanhedrin, noone would have ever been executed.

Comment: Likewise, according to the oral law, conviction requires the criminal to verbally declare to two valid witnesses, upon having been warned of the consequences of his act, that he is doing so with that in mind.

Comment: Thus, the specific, biblically mandated execution, does not appear to be specifically based on the value of compassion, which, instead is a conflicting value integrated independently, so as to accommodate (to a degree) both values.

Comment: @Loewian all understood but (and I have to check back in the gemara to give precise citations) there is IIRC discussion of death penalties having been carried out so murderous or not, its logic is up for discussion as practical as well as hypothetical. As to your first comment of these last ones, while being humane may not be the goal, if the point is death, then the method seems secondary so why create a set of levels of more and less humane?

Comment: I recall it to be connected vaguely to the 4 basic elements Rambam is talking about in Yesodey Hatorah - earth, water, wind and fire. They believed that because the sin is caused by damages to one of those elements, the penalty must correct it (kinda מידה כנגד מידה).

Comment: @AlBerko I was pointed to this statement by the Maharal (http://www.aspaklaria.info/040_MEM/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F.htm) which seems to put them in a geometric pattern as if the four penalties dissuaded people from straying in 4 particular "directions"

Comment: very relevant (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65576/arba-misos-beis-din-1-mitzvah-or-4/65893

Comment: Stones are to be found anywhere; no technology is needed to produce them, since they are already abundant in nature itself. Also, when a sound person reads the Scriptures, they usually identify with the sinner (being executed), not with its executors, since the purpose of the sacred texts is to draw attention to the severity of sin and evil, and to make one think twice before doing something that appears pleasant, but, in reality, is full of darkness.